# Python3/DataFrame: string indices must be integer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have got DataFrame with lists:

```
deviceId  timeInMilliseconds           callState  \
0  e4774cdda0793f86414e8b9140bb6db4       1455233230229  CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK   
1  e4774cdda0793f86414e8b9140bb6db4       1455233232239     CALL_STATE_IDLE   
2  270c1b084f3f146eb5787075158d9c53       1455233316723  CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK   
3  270c1b084f3f146eb5787075158d9c53       1455233324391     CALL_STATE_IDLE   
4  270c1b084f3f146eb5787075158d9c53       1455234721731  CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK   

  number  numberType      time        data day_of_the_week  \
0  609665996           0  00:27:10  2016-02-12               5   
1  609665996           0  00:27:12  2016-02-12               5   
2  126301484           1  00:28:36  2016-02-12               5   
3  126301484           1  00:28:44  2016-02-12               5   
4  126301484           1  00:52:01  2016-02-12               5
```

I want to get all data from those DataFrame when callState is equal to CALL_STATE_IDLE.

I tried like that:

```
data_all = [x for x in data if (x['callState'] == 'CALL_STATE_IDLE') ]
```

but I have 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you need to be doing

```
data_all = data[data['callState'] == 'CALL_STATE_IDLE']

data_all

                           deviceId  timeInMilliseconds        callState  \
1  e4774cdda0793f86414e8b9140bb6db4       1455233232239  CALL_STATE_IDLE
3  270c1b084f3f146eb5787075158d9c53       1455233324391  CALL_STATE_IDLE

      number  numberType      time        data  day_of_the_week
1  609665996           0  00:27:12  2016-02-12                5
3  126301484           1  00:28:44  2016-02-12                5
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, using `query`

```
In [871]: df.query('callState == "CALL_STATE_IDLE"')
Out[871]:
                           deviceId  timeInMilliseconds        callState  \
1  e4774cdda0793f86414e8b9140bb6db4       1455233232239  CALL_STATE_IDLE
3  270c1b084f3f146eb5787075158d9c53       1455233324391  CALL_STATE_IDLE

      number  numberType      time        data  day_of_the_week
1  609665996           0  00:27:12  2016-02-12                5
3  126301484           1  00:28:44  2016-02-12                5
```